# is there any way to set response header "X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff" in weblogic server or in domain level for locahost?

Tags: javascript, java, weblogic11g

Can anyone let me know if there is a way to add a response header globally for the localhost domain or WebLogic server?
adding header in filter level is what I tried for now,but I am wonder if there is a way to set it from the server level.